# Php Curl 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I am trying to duplicate the Http headers in Php Curl.

My http header is below

```
Host: plus.google.com

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 

Cookie:NID=67=pdjIQN5CUKVn0bRgAlqitBk7WHVivLsbLcr7QOWMn35Pq03N1WMy6kxYBPORtaQUPQrfMK4Yo0vVz8tH97ejX3q7P2lNuPjTOhwqaI2bXCgPGSDKkdFoiYIqXubR0cTJ48hIAaKQqiQi_lpoe6edhMglvOO9ynw; PREF=ID=52aa671013493765:U=0cfb5c96530d04e3:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1370266105:LM=1370341612:GM=1:S=Kcc6KUnZwWfy3cOl; OTZ=1800625_34_34__34_; S=talkgadget=38GaRzFbruDPtFjrghEtRw; SID=DQAAALoAAADHyIbtG3J_u2hwNi4N6UQWgXlwOAQL58VRB_0xQYbDiL2HA5zvefboor5YVmHc8Zt5lcA0LCd2Riv4WsW53ZbNCv8Qu_THhIvtRgdEZfgk26LrKmObye1wU62jESQoNdbapFAfEH_IGHSIA0ZKsZrHiWLGVpujKyUvHHGsZc_XZm4Z4tb2bbYWWYAv02mw2njnf4jiKP2QTxnlnKFK77UvWn4FFcahe-XTk8Jlqblu66AlkTGMZpU0BDlYMValdnU; HSID=A6VT_ZJ0ZSm8NTdFf; SSID=A9_PWUXbZLazoEskE; APISID=RSS_BK5QSEmzBxlS/ApSt2fMy1g36vrYvk; SAPISID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now in firexfox http header addon, when i press replay this works correct.But when i do the same via php cur using below code i get error

```
<?php

function poster($url,$fields_string){
        $ch = curl_init();
        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,array('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Cookie: NID=67=pdjIQN5CUKVn0bRgAlqitBk7WHVivLsbLcr7QOWMn35Pq03N1WMy6kxYBPORtaQUPQrfMK4Yo0vVz8tH97ejX3q7P2lNuPjTOhwqaI2bXCgPGSDKkdFoiYIqXubR0cTJ48hIAaKQqiQi_lpoe6edhMglvOO9ynw; PREF=ID=52aa671013493765:U=0cfb5c96530d04e3:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1370266105:LM=1370341612:GM=1:S=Kcc6KUnZwWfy3cOl; OTZ=1800625_34_34__34_; S=talkgadget=38GaRzFbruDPtFjrghEtRw; SID=DQAAALoAAADHyIbtG3J_u2hwNi4N6UQWgXlwOAQL58VRB_0xQYbDiL2HA5zvefboor5YVmHc8Zt5lcA0LCd2Riv4WsW53ZbNCv8Qu_THhIvtRgdEZfgk26LrKmObye1wU62jESQoNdbapFAfEH_IGHSIA0ZKsZrHiWLGVpujKyUvHHGsZc_XZm4Z4tb2bbYWWYAv02mw2njnf4jiKP2QTxnlnKFK77UvWn4FFcahe-XTk8Jlqblu66AlkTGMZpU0BDlYMValdnU; HSID=A6VT_ZJ0ZSm8NTdFf; SSID=A9_PWUXbZLazoEskE; APISID=RSS_BK5QSEmzBxlS/ApSt2fMy1g36vrYvk; SAPISID=ZIMOP9lJ_E8SLdkL/A32W20hPpwgd5Kg1J'));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields_string));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        return array($result,$last);
        curl_close($ch);
    }



    $url = "https://plus.google.com/_/sharebox/post/?source=frameless&spam=56&hl=en&ozv=es_oz_20130602.13_p3&f.sid=-834406139015290241&_reqid=358119&rt=j";
    $string = 'f.req=%5B%22%22%2C%22oz%3A105057244581488239720.13f0ec465f5.0%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%22%5B%5D%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Ctrue%2C%5B%5D%2Cfalse%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%2Cnull%2Cfalse%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5B337%2C336%2C335%2C0%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fadjmpw.com%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%7B%2240154698%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fadjmpw.com%22%2Cnull%2C%22DOMAIN%20ERROR%22%2C%22%5Cu30c9%5Cu30e1%5Cu30a4%5Cu30f3%5Cu30a6%5Cu30a7%5Cu30d6%5Cu306e%5Cu8a2d%5Cu5b9a%5Cu304c%5Cu898b%5Cu3064%5Cu304b%5Cu308a%5Cu307e%5Cu305b%5Cu3093.%20%5Cu8003%5Cu3048%5Cu3089%5Cu308c%5Cu308b%5Cu539f%5Cu56e0.%20%5Cu30c9%5Cu30e1%5Cu30a4%5Cu30f3%5Cu30a6%5Cu30a7%5Cu30d6%5Cu306e%5Cu8a2d%5Cu5b9a%5Cu304c%5Cu307e%5Cu3060%5Cu884c%5Cu308f%5Cu308c%5Cu3066%5Cu3044%5Cu306a%5Cu3044%5Cu3002%20%5Cu30c9%5Cu30e1%5Cu30a4%5Cu30f3%5Cu30a6%5Cu30a7%5Cu30d6%5Cu306e%5Cu8a2d%5Cu5b9a%5Cu304c%5Cu307e%5Cu3060%5Cu53cd%5Cu6620%5Cu3055%5Cu308c%5Cu3066%5Cu3044%5Cu306a%5Cu3044%5Cu3002(%5Cu53cd%5Cu6620%5Cu306b%5Cu306f%5Cu6570%5Cu6642%5Cu9593%5Cuff5e24%5Cu6642%5Cu9593%5Cu304b%5Cu304b%5Cu308b%5Cu3053%5Cu3068%5Cu304c%5Cu3042%5Cu308a%5Cu307e%5Cu3059)%3B%20%5Cu30c9%5Cu30e1%5Cu30a4%5Cu30f3%5Cu30a6%5Cu30a7%5Cu30d6%5Cu30fbDNS%5Cu306e%5Cu8a2d%5Cu5b9a%5Cu304c%5Cu8aa4%5Cu3063%5Cu3066%5Cu3044%5Cu308b%5Cu3002%20%5Cu30a2%5Cu30ab%5Cu30a6%5Cu30f3%5Cu30c8%5Cu304c%5Cu5b58%5Cu5728%5Cu3057%5Cu306a%5Cu3044%5Cu3001%5Cu5951%5Cu7d04%5Cu304c%5Cu7d42%5Cu4e86%5Cu3057%5Cu3066%5Cu3044%5Cu308b%5Cu3001%5Cu524a%5Cu9664%5Cu3055%5Cu308c%5Cu3066%5Cu3044%5Cu308b%5Cu3002%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%22%2F%2Fs2.googleusercontent.com%2Fs2%2Ffavicons%3Fdomain%3Dadjmpw.com%22%2C%5B%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%2C%22adjmpw.com%22%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%5D%7D%5D%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5B%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C1%5D%5D%2Cnull%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%22!A0Kqty2yd13VXUSIQmFRwsHOTgIAAACcUgAAABMqAOOd_e40c9ZGEcvCbLFeO4xd-bERNZUdpPVB47P7EAX_SOsuScB1gj-i9hJCjwcEohHLhq9-1lnTIG6wDZoXbyksjLzUxuna6V4JfCOO_eohj7MQnsKiVuhKHcHKrOqP8WDZ8dgmUIFNVubfBPNemcuPOd8eahSf-JP9-6XMqnKdNIlTWLYqQvQWfohWhqmeu6K_tFBRDoUweLCSttIlehy66khLWOebSYf8cuLx_VQRH4Mdq-P1Cc4JlKrBwwoQPW66-Tpbb11OhHDSd7uh7S-Md7NMwkJSVzfGnWZZ3ZCjc6Cgzg%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%5D&at=AObGSAh9hx7LgvgMum-4aVedQIfEJa8FgA%3A1370342318767&';
    echo "<pre>";
    $game = poster($url,$string);
    echo $game[0];
    ?>
```

The response header for my php curl is

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="response.txt"
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 10:46:03 GMT
Set-Cookie: NID=67=U68qmM7sSUNdgJY64JIEltRkmhYS7l9mTZXX7GL2Z0BpnYBgZL2FsVnjpAYUvToyBFzGY7SLGAS5Ko0K-N61I4VV7HTvIlZvX9ARxSxKR_KQtfjHDbqZ3pK_y-X7V-Oe;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 04-Dec-2013 10:46:03 GMT;HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

My post content, cookie , post url ..everything is same as http header addon in firefox.(works even when i am logged out) . But why do i get 403 error in my php curl ? how google detects the curl ?

Comment: Check P3P header in your response, If google blocking your curl access.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
function poster($url,$fields_string){
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'NID=67=pdjIQN5CUKVn0bRgAlqitBk7WHVivLsbLcr7QOWMn35Pq03N1WMy6kxYBPORtaQUPQrfMK4Yo0vVz8tH97ejX3q7P2lNuPjTOhwqaI2bXCgPGSDKkdFoiYIqXubR0cTJ48hIAaKQqiQi_lpoe6edhMglvOO9ynw; PREF=ID=52aa671013493765:U=0cfb5c96530d04e3:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1370266105:LM=1370341612:GM=1:S=Kcc6KUnZwWfy3cOl; OTZ=1800625_34_34__34_; S=talkgadget=38GaRzFbruDPtFjrghEtRw; SID=DQAAALoAAADHyIbtG3J_u2hwNi4N6UQWgXlwOAQL58VRB_0xQYbDiL2HA5zvefboor5YVmHc8Zt5lcA0LCd2Riv4WsW53ZbNCv8Qu_THhIvtRgdEZfgk26LrKmObye1wU62jESQoNdbapFAfEH_IGHSIA0ZKsZrHiWLGVpujKyUvHHGsZc_XZm4Z4tb2bbYWWYAv02mw2njnf4jiKP2QTxnlnKFK77UvWn4FFcahe-XTk8Jlqblu66AlkTGMZpU0BDlYMValdnU; HSID=A6VT_ZJ0ZSm8NTdFf; SSID=A9_PWUXbZLazoEskE; APISID=RSS_BK5QSEmzBxlS/ApSt2fMy1g36vrYvk; SAPISID=ZIMOP9lJ_E8SLdkL/A32W20hPpwgd5Kg1J');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
return array($result,$last);
}
```

Let me know if this works :)

Comment: Cool set useragent solved the problem thanks!
 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Use http for your plus.google link instead of https. Will that work?**

---

Maybe this will work. I've changed your user agent to the following:

```
<?php

// ADD THIS
$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';


function poster($url,$fields_string){
        $ch = curl_init();
        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,array('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Cookie: NID=67=pdjIQN5CUKVn0bRgAlqitBk7WHVivLsbLcr7QOWMn35Pq03N1WMy6kxYBPORtaQUPQrfMK4Yo0vVz8tH97ejX3q7P2lNuPjTOhwqaI2bXCgPGSDKkdFoiYIqXubR0cTJ48hIAaKQqiQi_lpoe6edhMglvOO9ynw; PREF=ID=52aa671013493765:U=0cfb5c96530d04e3:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1370266105:LM=1370341612:GM=1:S=Kcc6KUnZwWfy3cOl; OTZ=1800625_34_34__34_; S=talkgadget=38GaRzFbruDPtFjrghEtRw; SID=DQAAALoAAADHyIbtG3J_u2hwNi4N6UQWgXlwOAQL58VRB_0xQYbDiL2HA5zvefboor5YVmHc8Zt5lcA0LCd2Riv4WsW53ZbNCv8Qu_THhIvtRgdEZfgk26LrKmObye1wU62jESQoNdbapFAfEH_IGHSIA0ZKsZrHiWLGVpujKyUvHHGsZc_XZm4Z4tb2bbYWWYAv02mw2njnf4jiKP2QTxnlnKFK77UvWn4FFcahe-XTk8Jlqblu66AlkTGMZpU0BDlYMValdnU; HSID=A6VT_ZJ0ZSm8NTdFf; SSID=A9_PWUXbZLazoEskE; APISID=RSS_BK5QSEmzBxlS/ApSt2fMy1g36vrYvk; SAPISID=ZIMOP9lJ_E8SLdkL/A32W20hPpwgd5Kg1J'));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        //CHANGE THIS
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields_string));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        return array($result,$last);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: nope localhost , i can even login to google via my localhost php curl